# Null value after constructor

Tags: java, constructor, null, nullpointerexception

```
class test
{
    public static myclass x;

    test() {
       try {
           x=new myclass();
           //x is not null here
       } catch(Exception e) {/*stuff*/}
       //not null here
    }

    //x is null here in any other member method
}
```

Please explain a reason for this behavior?
Isn't a constructor required to retain a value rather than losing it once a constructor block ends?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's happening without seeing some more code. Can you show us how and from where are you accessing `x`?

Comment: I am sorry Im through a mobile device. But the other class is a normal simple class with throws Exception for each method

Comment: I tried accessing x at all the commented places using x==null if statement

Comment: Are you accessing `x` in a static way? From probably a `static` method.?

Comment: If it reliably throws in the constructor too, you never get to assign x

Comment: Setting static field sin constructors is a bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be confusing static values with instance values.

`x` is static, but it's not initialized in a static initialization block.  It's only initialized when you create an *instance* of `test` (via the constructor for that instance).  Also note that it's going to be re-initialized any time you create a new instance of `test`, which is probably going to cause some very strange bugs for you.

In order for `x` to be initialized as a static value for the class, add it to a static initialization block:

```
class test
{
    public static myclass x;

    static
    {
        x=new myclass();
    }
}
```

This way `x` should only be initialized once, statically, when the runtime loads the class.  This would allow it to be accessed without first having to create an instance of `test`, as well as remove the bug of re-initializing it on any new instance of `test`.

Conversely, if this should instead be an *instance* value instead of a static value, you can simply change its declaration:

```
public myclass x;
```

Answer (score 1):

as such code is correct. but since the variable `x` is `static`, you might be accessing it before calling the constructor. in that case it will be null. As soon as, the constructor get to run for the first time, the value of x will be set to a new object.

if its you requirement to keep x static. initialize it in static initializer block. like:

```
class test
{
public static myclass x;
static {
    x = new myclass();
    }
}
```

or simply as:

```
class test
{
public static myclass x = new myclass();
}
```

Comment: Java doesnt permit non static because i have a main in this class. Thats why I checked after the constructor in another method. It was null there. However is I used the "new" at place of defenition itself, no error applied